# Gmap4rails: Render partial in Infowindow via model (not controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm able to render the `infowindow` partial via controller like this:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/layouts/map", :locals => { :object => person})
```

But I want to **render it via the model** in:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
 #code here  
end
```

How do I do that?

1) I'm showing **two types of records on my map and each one has a different color marker**. So I want to mention somewhere in the map to tell user which marker denotes what.How to do this?

2) what is **`sidebar`** in gmaps4rail?

3) **how to pass instance variables to the partial**?

Comment: you're not supposed to use partials in models, sidebar is documented

Comment: what about passing `instance varaibles`?

Comment: you're not supposed to use partials in models... but you can render basic strings

Comment: actually this was a huge design error from me. it should not even be possible to define that in models

Comment: @apneadiving that means I cannot add links to `infowindow`? :(

Comment: do it in controller, really

Comment: @apneadiving ohk. what about passing instance variables?

Comment: locals hash is dedicated to that in partials, you already pasted an example

Comment: I tried to access the `person` in the partial but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/layouts/map", :locals => { :object => person})
```

with:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/layouts/map", :locals => { :person => person})
```

Comment: can I pass the same **`person`** instance variable to my other views?

Comment: a partial is a partial, you can reuse it

Comment: I added a link to the infowindow which triggers a **bootstrap modal**. I added the modal `html` below `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>`. Now the `person` variable is available in `infowindow` only. How to access it outside infowindow? like in the view where `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>` is there?

Comment: just assign it to an instance variable, like all other variables you need in your view

Comment: Ohk.I had thought of that but I was wrongly thinking that defining a instance variable inside the `@json` is only for the `map` thing. thanks anyway.

Comment: Well that doesn't work properly.what is `person`? It is array of all the `persons'` right? Now if I iterate over the `person` variable in the infowindow it works fine. But if I assign `person` to instance variable and use it in other view it just gives a single person.